# Safe to return class template from function with C-style linkage?

Tags: c++, templates, linkage

If the caller and the function both agree on the memory layout of a class (i.e. same compiler and settings), is it safe for a function with C-style linkage to return a class instantiated from a class template?

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" std::vector<int> foo()
{
    return {{1, 2, 3}};
}

int main()
{
    const auto v = foo();
    for (const auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program compiles and runs with g++ 4.9.2 and clang 3.5. g++ issues no warnings but clang issues the following:

> test.cpp:4:29: warning: 'foo' has C-linkage specified, but returns
>   incomplete type 'std::vector' which could be incompatible with C
>   [-Wreturn-type-c-linkage]

This error doesn't make sense to me because `std::vector<int>` is not an incomplete type. The fact that this code creates an instance of `std::vector<int>` demonstrates that `std::vector<int>` is a complete type.

Comment: The word "incomplete" is inaccurate and irrelevant.  The warning is just telling you that the function signature is not compatible with the C language, even though you have selected C linkage.  You can safely call it from C++, and using C linkage for such a function might make sense if you are using it with `dlsym` (Note that it doesn't make as much sense in Windows, where standard library types cannot be exchanged between separately compiled shared libraries.  And even on Linux, the whole libstdc++ vs libc++ issue makes it problematic)

Comment: @BenVoigt `dlsym` is indeed the usage I had in mind. Why can't you pass standard library types between separately compiled shared libraries on Windows? That sounds like a ridiculous limitation.

Comment: To share types across libraries they must be (1) fully-specified (including the allocator, etc) and (2) standard-layout.  The standard library types are neither.  And separately compiled libraries may use different versions of the headers, or different compiler options, or different compilers that apply different layout, etc.  So the One Definition Rule gets violated.

Comment: Each DLL in windows has it's own heap, so if you do something like `vector<int> v = foo(); v.push_back(81);` in your main program and the `push_back` means that  `v` needs to have it's internal storage reallocated, then the "wrong" heap.

Comment: @MatsPetersson do you mean that you might end up writing to incorrect heap and access violation occurs?

Comment: Yes, unless the allocator for `vector` is such that it knows what heap it should use...

Comment: @MatsPetersson does this mean you might end up or you WILL end up writing to memory you are not allowed to? Can it succeed sometimes and fail only occasionally?

Comment: Exactly what you end up with is "undefined behaviour" - so the exact behaviour "depends on circumstances". However, you don't have memory protection for data access between DLL and main program - different process will have different data storage and protection from overwriting, but any part of the application, whether it's the "main" program, one DLL or another DLL can access all the data of any part of the application, whether it's the main app or inside "its" DLL, or some other DLL)

Comment: @mars every dll has a different heap if you compile it that way.  If you compile using a dll standard library that agrees, that is not true.

Comment: @MatsPetersson so how should one handle a case like the one you mentioned: vector<int> v = foo(); v.push_back(81); ? Does this mean you cannot do operations that might result in reallocation in that case?

Comment: Pretty much, and I think that's what Ben was saying too.

Comment: Could you pass back a REFERENCE via the function params, even if it had C linkage (rather than a return value)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a shared_ptr return of objects across a C interface.  The nice thing about that is the proper deleter will be called on the object when it is no longer accessible.

From:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

> The deleter associated to r is stored for future deletion of the managed object.

Also see Scott Meyers entry on this topic:

> Understanding how deleters work in Boost’s shared_ptr
>   http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_aha_moments.html

Even better is a discussion of the Cross DLL Problem in the accepted answer here:
[Is it OK to use boost::shared ptr in DLL interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958643/is-it-ok-to-use-boostshared-ptr-in-dll-interface)

Since the return type is not part of the name mangling of the function.  You should still be able use C-style linkage if you want to.

Comment: Now you have the problem of cleaning up the `shared_ptr` itself.  It has metadata that needs to be deallocated, if that is not done with the matching allocator, you're in just as much trouble as if the memory for the main object were freed with the wrong allocator.

Comment: Also, you've linked to a question where the accepted answer is very very wrong.

Comment: A shared pointer is allocated on the stack.  According to the cppreference, it has its own allocator which it uses to handle internal memory.  When the shared pointer goes out of scope, it uses the proper deleter to free its internal memory.

Comment: "It has its own allocator"... to exactly the same degree that `std::vector` does.  The problem is whether both sides of the boundary agree on that allocator.  On Linux, it's easy -- make sure both use the same C++ library, either libc++ or libstdc++ -- no mixing.  On Windows, unless both sides are built with the same build process (same compiler, same version, same defines, and `/MD` compiler option) then they won't agree on the allocator.  And that doesn't even touch on the fact that the Standard doesn't specify the layout of `shared_ptr`, it can be different in every module.